# Database design issue - variable amount of data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, nosql

## The situation

Currently I am creating a web service which collects data. The current design of the database is in the picture below but in short words:

- A group creates properties
- A property creates departments
- A department creates questions

[image: Current database design]
Because every department has a different amount of questions (no maximum) I am very confused on how to actually store the data. I have spend a large period of time trying to figure out whether I should implement a NoSQL solution for this situation.

### Things which are a no go

I've read that storing a JSON string into a single column in MySQL is bad for performance and makes querying of those values slow, unreliable and/or impossible.

Also creating a separate table for 'answers' linked to a 'person id' for example will create so much rows in a very small amount of time and I think this is not really scalable.

## My questions

> 1. What is an efficient way to store data with a variable amount of 'columns'
>
>    > Is this possible with MySQL / phpmyadmin?
> 2. If it is not, is there a way to use NoSQL on a shared hosting account (thus without installation)?

Thank you!

Comment: I see no arguments whatsoever against a normalized relational model.

Comment: @DanBracuk Just to make sure I understand, you would create another table containing every 'person' that fills in a form and then insert a row into a table 'answers' for every question that is answered (linking to the person with an id)? Are there any limitations in speed when having a large amount of answers?